# Kotlin Coroutines causing large delay in tests even where they are not run

Tags: kotlin, parallel-processing, memory-leaks, kotlin-coroutines

In our project, where we currently have about 14k tests, I've been experimenting with adding Kotlin's coroutine's to parallize a major loop. This sped up the relevant test by about a third, but when running all of the tests, it's caused a massive slow down as tests are gone through, and for me, eventually failing for lack of heap space. I'm curious if I've made a memory leak or some similar such error. I'm new to parallel processing, so easily could have done something wrong in just the coding as well.

The major loop looked something like:

```
listOfStuffToParellize.flatMap {
  ExpensiveCodeHere
}
```

I changed that to

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.awaitAll
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers


companion object {
  suspend fun <A, B> Iterable<A>.pmap(f: suspend (A) -> B): List<B> = coroutineScope {
    map { async { f(it) } }.awaitAll()
  }
}

runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
  listOfStuffToParellize.pmap { 
    ExpensiveCodeHere
  }
}.flatten()
```

I got the pmap function from https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/05/04/parallel-map-in-kotlin/.

Now, when I run any all of the tests together, I get a massive decrease in speed before hitting a java heapspace error, as I've run out of memory, on top of having a massive slowdown in speed of running the thousands of tests before hand. Looking at the rate at which the tests take vs dev, it seems to start at about the same speed, then slow down over as more tests are run. This includes tests which do not use the affected code at all, which is the vast majority, and where the tests finally slow to a crawl.

But when running those tests again, just by themselves, they run much faster. This is making me think I have a memory leak of some sort, but having never experienced that before, I cannot say for sure.

I've also tried replacing the dispatcher with `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().asCoroutineDispatcher()` as suggested [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3192), but this did not solve the problem.

So tl; dr: Does this sound like a memory leak problem caused by my code, or something else?

Comment: I guess `ExpensiveCodeHere` is using a lot of memory? If you use a lot of memory to do it in sequence, this could be using like 32 times as much (depending on number of CPU cores).

Comment: I've only got four cores on my laptop, and the slowdown and fail doesn't fail *during* the tests which use parallel part, but afterwards. Would it not have garbage collected by that point? This is what leads me to think that there's a memory leak.

Comment: There is no sign of a leak in the code you've posted, but maybe it's possible `ExpensiveCodeHere` is doing something that could cause a leak.

Comment: I agree that this code itself looks fine and it's likely an issue with either `ExpensiveCodeHere` or maybe some other aspect of the test setup.

Comment: Currently, I'm going to see if replacing it with a .parallelStreams() magically solves the problem. If not, I'd assume the problem is somewhere deep in ExpensiveCodeHere. Any idea how to go about this? I'd accept that as an answer, as it would isolate my problem one way or another.

Comment: This method did isolate the problem. And the solution was found through this method.